# How to configure two IBM Worklight Server v6.1 to one IBM HTTP Server so that both the App Server would get equal number of hits?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, websphere, worklight-server, server-configuration

Am having two IBM Worklight v6.1 App servers configured to one IBM HTTP Web Server. **ISSUE** Number  of hits on one of the App Server is much more than the other server say for eg: App1 is having <20 hits whereas the other server is having 5 hits. I want the traffic to be distributed uniformly. Please help me in resolving the issue.

In the present Scenario Load Balancer is configured before Web Servers.If I follow as mentioned in the following link"https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/urun_rwlm_member_inst.html" will I be able to achieve uniform traffic hits in App Servers.

Comment: Is this WAS-ND a cluster?

Comment: yes its cluster

Answer (score 0):

Your query is not specific to MFP / Worklight server. This setting has to be achieved using WebSphere Application Server ND load balancing settings.

WebSphere Application server cluster settings gives an option to set weight for the cluster member.Weight controls the number of requests that are directed to the application server.

For more details, refer to the [Cluster settings](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/urun_rwlm_member_inst.html) link.

Comment: In the current scenario the Load Balancer is configured before Web Server, and all the web servers are getting uniform hits,but from web server to app server am not getting uniform hits. Please guide in solving this issue.

Comment: Have you tried out the link and still see the problem? There is no issue with MFP. The topology and WAS/IHS configuration should be verified

Comment: Am not saying theres an issue with MFP, am askg where shld i make changes ? Should i make changes in Webserver plugin.

Comment: I would suggest you start with Cluster settings in WAS ND console and then propagating the changes to IHS plugin